# SQL min / max group by question

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have something like the following data structure:

```
Category    StartDateTime       EndDateTime
===============================================
1           12/1/2009 12:00     12/1/2009 12:12
1           12/1/2009 04:00     12/1/2009 04:20
2           12/2/2009 10:15     12/2/2009 10:22
2           12/2/2009 11:00     12/2/2009 11:01
```

I want the min StartDateTime and max EndDateTime for each Category.  Like this:

```
Category    MinStartDateTime    MaxEndDateTime
===============================================
1           12/1/2009 12:00     12/1/2009 04:20
2           12/2/2009 10:15     12/2/2009 11:01
```

Using min & max with a group by Category doesn't seem to work:

```
select
    Category,
    min(StartDateTime) [MinStartDateTime],
    max(EndDateTime) [MaxDateTime]
from
    MyTable
group by
    Category
order by
    Category,
    StartDateTime,
    EndDateTime
```

I also tried two inner joins on a sub-query for each min and max statement, however it seems to be excluding some records:

```
select distinct
    T1.Category,
    T1.StartDateTime [MinStartDateTime],
    T1.EndDateTime [MaxEndDateTime]

from
    MyTable T1

inner join
    (select
        Category,
        min(StartDateTime) [MinStartDateTime]
     from
        MyTable
     group by
        Category) T2
on T2.Category = T1.Category and T2.MinStartDateTime = T1.StartDateTime

inner join
    (select
        Category,
        max(EndDateTime) [MaxEndDateTime]
     from
        MyTable
     group by
        Category) T3
on T3.Category = T1.Category and T3.MaxEndDateTime = T1.EndDateTime

order by
    T1.Category,
    T1.encodeStartDateTime,
    T1.encodeEndDateTime
```

Any ideas?  The database is Sybase ASE which should be SQL-92 compliant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first solution looks correct except for the order by clause; try:

```
select
    Category,
    min(StartDateTime) [MinStartDateTime],
    max(EndDateTime) [MaxDateTime]
from MyTable
group by
    Category
order by
    Category,
    MinStartDateTime,
    MaxDateTime
```

Comment: Since the Category will be unique by virtue of the grouping, there is no need to order (redundantly) by either time.

Comment: Yes, using the correct field names in the order by corrected the results.  I'm embarrassed by the oversight.  Thanks for brining it to my attention!

Comment: Or you could have ordered the result set by the ordinal number of the column (ORDER BY 1, 2, 3).